# focus-in-hook and buffer-file-name

Tags: hooks, focus

I have the following in my init file

```
(defun message-buffer-file-name-or-nothing ()
  "Mode line proxy."
  (if buffer-file-name
      (message "[%s] %s"
           (format-time-string "%H:%M:%S")
           (buffer-file-name)))
  )
(add-hook 'focus-in-hook 'message-buffer-file-name-or-nothing)
```

and it worked great, until recently when it started echoing NOT the file-name of the buffer I was switching to but instead the file-name of the bufer I was switching FROM. I have no idea what happened since I didn't tamper with anything and I can't recall updating emacs recently either (25.3.1).

Output of `C-h v focus-in-hook` is `message-buffer-file-name-or-nothing`, nothing else hooks it. I guess this gets executed before buffer-file-name gets updated? But this is weird since it didn't work like this previously. Anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: With emacs -Q and the snippet from op in the scratch buffer, this behaviour is reproduced. This has got to qualify as a bug, right?

Comment: Although only when using the WMs switch-focus functions. Using other-frame and similar emacs native functions, it works as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what's causing this so I don't have a robust solution. Only a workaround...

```
(defadvice handle-switch-frame (around switch-frame-message-name)
  (message-buffer-file-name-or-nothing)
  ad-do-it
  (message-buffer-file-name-or-nothing))
(ad-activate 'handle-switch-frame)
```

Works for me on i3/emacs 25.3.1